# Is there a way to avoid the "select account" prompt while logging out of Microsoft AAD with oAuth?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I'm writing a JS application where the user can do front-end authentication with Microsoft, oAuth2 & openId connect. I need the user to be able to switch accounts, so logout then login another account. In the logout flow, the user is asked to "pick an account to sign out of" even if there is only one account (see [popup screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xCap.png)). How could I skip this prompt?

I know that for login you can pass `login_hint` or `sid` (session ID from ID token). I tried this without success: 
- With the `login_hint` in the url's querystring I still have the 'select account' prompt (the login_hint is the `preferred_username` for the user, which I successfully use for login)
- With the `sid` and `iss` in the url's querystring I get an `InvalidSessionId` error: `AADSTS90007 Bad request. The passed session ID can't be parsed.` The url looks like this :

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout?sid=M.1234567890123456789&iss=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.microsoftonline.com%2F1234567a-1a23-1a2b-a123-12a345b67cde%2Fv2.0
```

(i tried with both encoded url as above and with the raw url for the iss, with the same result)
What am I doing wrong here?

To give a bit more context, this prompt bothers me because I need to achieve a silent logout. The reason for this is that the oAuth popup to login is blocked by the browser, since it arrives long after the user clicked the button to switch accounts. Also, it seems that this prompt disables the `post_logout_redirect_uri`, so I can't use a redirect flow either.
See this github issue : https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/735

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: No, I just resigned to logging out with the prompt. However, if you want a silent logout to use as part of a "change accout" feature, you can just do a regular sign in on top of the actual session without logging out.

Comment: @EwanCoder Did you ever find this out?

Comment: @S.tenBrinke yes, apparently with the new (v2.0) API it is not supported by Microsoft, all the solutions that actually don't show this popup screen use the old one (v1.x) API. Downgrading to the old API isn't an option for us - so we still live with the popup screen.

Comment: @EwanCoder thanks for your reply! I was wondering if you have a source for this?

Comment: No I don't, as far as I know our team had email conversation with Microsoft but I cannot confirm this as I was not participating in this discussion.

Comment: I am also searching answer for this question. but found this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/544011/bypass-the-azure-ad-sso-choose-an-account-prompt-w.html. May be this helps you